# What do the powers of each character do?

Tags: the-cave

There are a boatload of characters in "The Cave", and I see that each one has their own special power.  However, the game doesn't really explain to you what those powers do.  Some, like the Time Traveler's ***teleport*** are pretty self explanatory - but many others like the Monk's ***chanting*** or the Knight's ***angel stance*** seem much less obvious to me.  I think it is safe to assume that all of these abilities are used to interact with objects, but I'd like an idea of what each one does - so I don't miss chances to use them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Adventurer**

The Adventuer's special ability involves her use of a grappling hook/rope combination allowing her to swing over wide expanseses or to climb in areas where there is no other rope available. There must be a hook point present in order for her to use her special ability.

**Hillbilly**

He have the ability to infinitely breath underwater.

**Knight**

Knight have the Guardian Angel ability making him able to fall from great distances, and be protected from damage.

**Monk**

The Monk's special ability is "Telekinesis". With this ability the Monk is able to move nearby objects to him, often times when they are behind walls.

**Scientist**

She can hack consoles which you find across your journey.

**Time Traveller**

Her special ability is teleportation across a small distance, often through objects.

**Twins**

Their special ability is to place clones of themselves performing tasks. Such as using one to pull a lever, then place a clone copy so it continues to be held for some time.

***Source***: [Characters](http://www.ign.com/wikis/the-cave/Characters)